# iOS Core Data - Deletes not reflected until App Restart

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios4

I am successfully adding and updating records in my core data on a second thread without issue.

However, deletes don't seem to take effect until I stop and restart the App.  So the delete is obviously working to a extent.  I read the data before loading the tableview and don't do anything different for when there has been a deletion.

The code I'm using is

```
....fetch records....
BOOL deleteGem = FALSE;
if ([[attributeDict objectForKey:@"headline"] hasPrefix:@"VOID"])
    deleteGem = TRUE;

    if ([mutableFetchResults count] == 0) {
    // not there so create a new one    
        if (!deleteGem) {
            // so create a new one unless it needs deleting
            gem = (Gem *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Gem" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
            [gem setID:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"ID"]];
        }
    } else {

        // already exists so either get it and then update or delete it
        gem = [mutableFetchResults objectAtIndex:0];

        if (deleteGem) {
            // delete it if required
            [managedObjectContext deleteObject:gem];
            gemDeletes ++;
        }
    }
    .....
```

Later on I have a method to save any updates including:

```
    NSError *error;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) { 
    ....
```

Any ideas warmly welcomed...

**Edit - with full answer based on @TechZen's answer..**

---

**Register for notifications of updates on the 2nd thread in viewDidLoad**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleSaveNotification:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil];
```

**Unregister for notifications in viewDidUnload**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil];
```

Handle the update in the main thread (a new method in the view controller)

```
-(void)handleSaveNotification:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:aNotification];
}
```

Comment: Okay, color me confused. Are you displaying the data in the tableView DIRECTLY from coreData or are you buffering it in an NSArray/NSDictionary? If you are buffering, are you deleting the item from the NSArray/NSDictionary?

Comment: No, am buffering in an array but I refresh this and that works fine for inserts and updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to merge the background context with the foreground context if you want the changes made in the background context to show up in the foreground context.